# Use `j` to select the join column of `x` and all its non-join columns

Tags: r, data.table

I have two data tables:

```
library(data.table)
d1 <- data.table(grp = c("a", "c", "b", "a"), val = c(2, 3, 6, 7), y1 = 1:4, y2 = 5:8)

d2 <- data.table(grp = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 2),
                 from = rep(c(1, 5), each = 3), to = rep(c(4, 10), each = 3), z = 11:16)
```

I perform a non-equi join where the value 'val' in 'd1' should fall within the range defined by 'from' and 'to' in 'd2' for each group 'grp'.

```
d1[d2, on = .(grp, val >= from, val <= to), nomatch = 0]
#    grp val y1 y2 val.1  z
# 1:   a   1  1  5     4 11
# 2:   c   1  2  6     4 13
# 3:   a   5  4  8    10 14
# 4:   b   5  3  7    10 15
```

In the output, the join variables are from `i` ('val' and 'val.1', with the values of respectively 'from' and 'to' in 'd2'). However, I would like to have `x`'s join column instead. Now, because...

> Columns of `x` can now be referred to using the prefix `x.` and is particularly useful during joining to refer to `x`'s join columns as they are otherwise masked by `i`'s.

...this could be achieved by specifying `val = x.val` in `j`:

```
d1[d2, .(grp, val = x.val, z), on = .(grp, val >= from, val <= to), nomatch = 0]
```

In order to avoid typing all non-join columns (possibly many) from `x` in `j`, my current work-around is to join the above with the original data, which gives the desired result:

```
d1[d1[d2, .(grp, val = x.val, z), on = .(grp, val >= from, val <= to), nomatch = 0]
   , on = .(grp, val)]
#    grp val y1 y2  z
# 1:   a   2  1  5 11
# 2:   c   3  2  6 13
# 3:   a   7  4  8 14
# 4:   b   6  3  7 15
```

However, this seems a bit clumsy. Thus my question: how can I select the join column from `x` and all non-join columns from `x` in `j` in one go?

---

PS I have considered switching the `x` and `i` data sets, and the conditions in `on`. Although that produces the desired join values, it still requires post-processing (deleting, renaming and reordering of columns).

Comment: I don't know the post-processing is limited to however many non-equi cols you have... doesn't look too bad, something like `d2[d1, on=.(grp, from <= val, to >= val), nomatch=0][, \`:=\`(val = from, from = NULL, to = NULL)][]`

Comment: based on @docendo's [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43642191/2204410) myabe this: `idx <- d2[d1, on = .(grp, from <= val, to >= val), which = TRUE]; d1[, z := d2$z[idx]][]`?

Comment: Fyi, I added a variant of @Jaap 's comment to my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> PS I have considered switching the x and i data sets, and the conditions in on. Although that produces the desired join values, it still requires post-processing (deleting, renaming and reordering of columns).

The amount of post processing is limited by how many `on=` cols there are:

```
d2[d1, on=.(grp, from <= val, to >= val), nomatch=0][, 
  `:=`(val = from, from = NULL, to = NULL)][]
```

That doesn't seem too bad.

---

Following @Jaap's comment, here's another way, adding columns to `d1` with an update join:

```
nm2 = setdiff(names(d2), c("from","to","grp"))
d1[d2, on=.(grp, val >= from, val <= to), (nm2) := mget(sprintf("i.%s", nm2))]
```

This makes sense here because the desired output is essentially `d1` plus some columns from `d2` (since each row of `d1` matches at most one row of `d2`).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps use `foverlaps` from `data.table`

```
#create duplicate range
setDT(d1)[,`:=`(val1 = val)]

#setkey
setkey(d1, grp, val, val1)
setkey(d2, grp, from, to)

#join
d_merge <- foverlaps(d1, d2, nomatch = NA)
setDT(d_merge)[,`:=`(from = NULL,
                     to = NULL,
                     val1 = NULL)]
d_merge
#    grp z val y1 y2
#1:   a 11   2  1  5
#2:   a 14   7  4  8
#3:   b 15   6  3  7
#4:   c 13   3  2  6
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion (+1)! It indeed gives the desired result. However, the main focus of my question is the use of `j` in this setting. Cheers.

Comment: @Henrik Thanks. I agree!