# Idioms for enabling type dispatching

Tags: r, class, date, date-range, dispatch

There's a few questions here, I would be satisfied if any one of them was answered sufficiently well.

#### Background - what is the end goal?

I am interested in representing a date-range in R. Bare-minimum requirement is that we represent a start and end date, which can easily be done using a length-two date vector. Additionally, it would be nice to extend this object into a Class which further

- supplies a name to each range (i.e. a character string)
- enables the (easy) use of `dplyr::between` operator

#### Shortcomings of my previous approach

I've previously represented each range as a length-two date vector. The upside here is that I don't rely on any external dependencies and my data structure is so lightweight that it's not a hassle to program with. The downside is that I'm tired of having to access the `beg` and `end` of the date range via the `[` operator and arguments `1` and `2` respectively (arguably less interpretable than if we had a class implementation).

Also, we ultimately deal with a sequence of date-ranges (i.e. a vector), and so abstracting away the `DateRange` is helpful before we start nesting data structures. I do not want to use a list of length-two date vectors nor do I wish to use a data.frame with two rows, each column being interpreted as a date-range.

#### Where have I looked?

I've looked at `lubridate` package and have considered inheriting from a `Interval` class. The downside to starting with this inheritance is that I don't think S4 is necessary for my use case. I just need a few simple data attributes and a nice API for calling `dplyr::between`.

An ideal solution might just extend the `lubridate::Interval` class to hold a name, an end date (could be a method as this info already stored in Interval via `@start + @.Data`), and extend `dplyr::between` to play nicely with said class.

#### What have I tried?

Here's a rough implementation of what I'm looking for:

```
# 3 key attributes: beg, end, and name.
MyInterval <- function(beg, end, name = NULL) {
    if (class(beg) == "character") beg <- as.Date(beg)
    if (class(end) == "character") end <- as.Date(end)
    if (is.null(name)) name <- as.character(beg)
    structure(.Data = list('beg' = beg, 'end' = end, 'name' = name), class = "MyInterval")
}
```

Now, I would like to be able to overload the `between` operator such that I may call it as follows: `between(x, MyInterval)`, where we notice that `dplyr::between(x, lo, hi)` expects three arguments. To try and accomplish this, I've tried to set up type dispatching as follows:

```
between <- function(...) UseMethod('between')
between.MyInterval <- function(interval, x) {
    if (class(x) == "character") x <- as.Date(x)
    dplyr::between(x, interval$beg, interval$end)
}
between.default <- function(x, lo, hi) dplyr::between(x, lo, hi)
```

The reason I chose to use `...` in the prototype for `between` is that the order of arguments currently differ between `between.MyInterval` and `between.default`. Is there a better way to code this up? I believe the behavior is as desired (to within a first glance)

```
i <- MyInterval("2012-01-01", "2012-12-31")
between(i, "2012-02-01") # Dispatches to between.MyInterval. Returns True as expected.
between(150, 100, 200)   # Dispatches to dplyr::between. Good, we didn't break anything?
```

#### Thank you

Any criticisms are welcomed. I know that `between` is a function that doesn't do type-dispatching out of the box, and so implementing this myself raises a code smell.

Comment: You might also want to look at `data.table`'s `inrange`-function. See for an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43642205/2204410).

Answer (score 2):

A possibility is to use `data.table`'s `inrange`-function.

First, let's make an interval:

```
my.interval <- function(beg, end) data.table(beg = as.Date(beg), end = as.Date(end))
mi <- my.interval("2012-01-01", "2012-12-31")
```

Now you can do:

```
> as.Date("2012-02-01") %inrange% mi
[1] TRUE
```

Or define you own `inrange`-function:

```
my.inrange <- function(x, intv) data.table::inrange(as.Date(x), intv$beg, intv$end)
```

With that you can do:

```
> my.inrange("2012-02-01", mi)
[1] TRUE
```

As @Frank commented, you can make an infix variant of `my.inrange` too:

```
`%my.inrange%` <- my.inrange
```

now you can use it in the following notation as well:

```
"2012-02-01" %my.inrange% mi
```

Which is similar to the infix notation of `data.table`'s `between` and `inrange` functions.