# Filter dataframe between values in two vectors and add results to list in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe of values and would like to use two vectors to specify where to filter between values in a dataframe, and then add the output of each filter to list.

For instance

```
mydata <- data.frame(x = 1:20)

v <- c(1,5,9)
v1 <- c(3,8,18)

expected_output <- list(c(1:3), c(5:8), c(9:18))
```

I have been using:

```
library(dplyr)
mydata <- mydata %>% 
  filter(between(x, v, v1))
```

which worked fine when I just needed to filter between two values ie between `v[1]`  and `v1[1]`, but now I need to filter between hundereds of pairs its not up to scratch.
I've tried lapply, as below and for loops, but im either not constructing them right, or using the wrong tool for the job.

```
out <- lapply(mydata, function(filter(between(x, t, t1)))
```

Cheers!

Comment: Related, although not a `list` as output: [Subset by multiple ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43641874/subset-by-multiple-ranges); [Efficient way to filter one data frame by ranges in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454565/efficient-way-to-filter-one-data-frame-by-ranges-in-another); [Filter by ranges supplied by two vectors, without a join operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44621700/filter-by-ranges-supplied-by-two-vectors-without-a-join-operation); `filter(mydata, data.table::inrange(x, v, v1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Tidyverse Solution 1 (using purrr's `map2`):

```
library(tidyverse)
map2(v, v1, ~ filter(mydata, x >= .x & x <= .y))
```

#### Tidyverse Solution 2 (this time with `map`)

```
map(1:length(v), ~ mydata[mydata$x >= v[.] & mydata$x <= v1[.],])
```

#### For Loop Solution

```
result <- list()
for (i in 1:length(v)) {
  result[[i]] <- filter(mydata, x >= v[i] & x <= v1[i])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Base R:

```
lapply(X = seq_along(v), function(x, data, v, v1){
                            data[v[x]:v1[x], ]
       },
       v = v, v1 = v1, data = mydata)
```

Comment: I wonder if this would work in a less contrived example than the one provided. For instance, if `mydata <- data.frame(x = c(1:20, 1:10)`, I think it would miss the rows at the end of the data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try `mapply`, which is the 'multivariate' version of `lapply` where you can iterate over multiple lists at once. Mapply takes a function to be applied first, and then the different vectors/lists in which the arguments that need to be supplied to the function.

```
mapply(function(x,y) mydata[mydata$x >= x & mydata$x <= y,'x'], v, v1)
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 5 6 7 8

[[3]]
 [1]  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
df_ranges <- data.frame(v,v1)

apply(df_ranges, 1, function(x, tab)  {tab[between(tab, x[1], x[2])]}, tab = mydata)
```