# What does < stand for in data.table joins with on=

Tags: r, data.table, left-join

Joining the data tables:

```
X <- data.table(A = 1:4, B = c(1,1,1,1)) 
#    A B
# 1: 1 1
# 2: 2 1
# 3: 3 1
# 4: 4 1

Y <- data.table(A = 4)
#    A
# 1: 4
```

via

```
X[Y, on = .(A == A)]
#    A B
# 1: 4 1
```

returns the expected result. However, I would expect the line:

```
X[Y, on = .(A < A)]
#    A B
# 1: 4 1
# 2: 4 1
# 3: 4 1
```

to return

```
   A B
1: 1 1
2: 2 1
3: 3 1
```

because the keyword `on`:

> Indicate which columns in x should be joined with which columns in i  along with the type of binary operator to join with

according to `?data.table`. The way the joining is done is not explicitly mentioned, and certainly it is not as I have guessed. How exactly `<` joins columns in x with columns in i?

Comment: A side note: you can simplify `X[Y, on = .(A == A)]` to `X[Y, on = .(A)]` or `X[Y, on = "A"]`

Comment: See also `?data.table` about the `j` argument: "Columns of `x` can now be referred to using the prefix `x.` and is particularly useful during joining to refer to `x`'s join columns as they are otherwise masked by `i`'s"

Comment: Related-ish: [Use `j` to select the join column of `x` and all its non-join columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42329157/use-j-to-select-the-join-column-of-x-and-all-its-non-join-columns)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When doing a non-equi join like `X[Y, on = .(A < A)]` [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) returns the `A`-column from `Y` (the `i`-data.table).

To get the desired result, you could do:

```
X[Y, on = .(A < A), .(A = x.A, B)]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    A B
> 1: 1 1
> 2: 2 1
> 3: 3 1
> ```

In the next release, [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) will return both `A` columns. [See here for the discussion](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/2706).

Answer (score 8):

You're partially correct. The missing piece of the puzzle is that (currently) when you perform any join, including a non-equi join with `<`, a single column is returned for the join colum (`A` in your example). This columns takes the values from the `data.table` on the right side of the join, in this case the values in `A` from `Y`.

Here's an illustrated example:

[image: Illustration of current non-equi join behaviour]

We're planning to change this behaviour in a future version of `data.table` so that both columns will be returned in the case of non-equi joins. See pull requests https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/2706 and https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/3093.