# Filter rows dataframe based on condition in different dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two dataframes: df1 and df2 (see example below). df1 contains a numeric start and end value per character id. df2 contains multiple events per character id, including a numeric time value.

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data_frame(id = c("A", "B"),
                  start = c(2, 3),
                  end = c(5, 9))

df2 <- data_frame(id = c(rep("A", 4), rep("B", 4)),
                  time = c(1, 3, 5, 8, 2, 3, 4, 10),
                  keep = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE))
```

I am trying to filter events in df2 using dplyr based on the time value being equal to or in between the start and end values per id in df1. So the filter is "df2$time >= df1$start & df2$time <= df1$end" which should be executed for each id separatly. I've added a logical column "keep" to show which rows I want to keep in df2.

How can I execute this filter for each id? Preferably using dplyr. This should be the endresult:

```
df2 %>%
  filter(keep == TRUE)
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about something like this, with `dplyr`:

```
  df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2) %>%                       #joining to have one dataset
  filter(time <= end, time >= start) %>%   # filter, you can use <, > in case
  select(-c(2,3))                          # remove useless column if necessary

# A tibble: 4 x 3
  id     time keep 
  <chr> <dbl> <lgl>
1 A         3 TRUE 
2 A         5 TRUE 
3 B         3 TRUE 
4 B         4 TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Using the non-equi join capability of [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table):

```
# load the package and convert the dataframes to data.tables
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)
setDT(df2)

# non-equi join
df2[df1
    , on = .(id, time >= start, time <= end)
    , .(id, time = x.time)]
```

which gives:

> ```
>    id time
> 1:  A    3
> 2:  A    5
> 3:  B    3
> 4:  B    4
> ```

What this does:

- `setDT()` converts a data.frame to a data.table
- You join `df1` with `df2`. by using `on = .(id, time >= start, time <= end)` you join on the exact match of `id` while at the same time `time` has to higher or equal to `start` from `df1` and lower or equal to `end` from `df1`.
- When doing a non-equi join, [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) will return the `time`-columns from `df1` (`start` and `end`) as `time` and `time` for the cases when the join-conditions are met ([see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52793127/2204410)). To get an idea of what I mean, you can just do `df2[df1, on = .(id, time >= start, time <= end)]`.
- By using `.(id, time = x.time)` you get the desired columns back. `x.time` refers to the `time`-column from the x-data.table which is `df2`.

Answer (score 0):

This also works

```
df2$start <- df1[match(df2$id, df1$id),"start"]
df2$end <- df1[match(df2$id, df1$id),"end"]
df2$keep <- df2$time>df2$start& df2$time<df2$end
result <- df2 %>%  filter(keep)
result
```