# data.table non-equivalent join returns some columns correctly and some replicated with last found value

Tags: r, join, data.table

In the example below, I have 5x5 grid (`A`) and 3 points(`B`), id'd with their respective coordinates.

The intended result is a list of all points from A that are 1 grid away from each of points from B. This is where non-equivalent join comes to the rescue. In general - it works as intended. In the resulting table (`result`), I have correct ID's of the points and correct ID's of the grid and I could work with that further.

What is bothering me are the `x` and `y` columns in the `result`. They were supposed to be coordinates of matched `grid_id`'s (look at `grid_id` column in the output - they are there, correct!), however, they appear to be stuck and the last matched point for each point from `A`. **What should I change to make x and y as values corresponding to their `grid_id`, except for another join?**

This is my first approach to data.table but I need it for better performance on few million rows.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

limit <- 1

A <- expand.grid(x = c(1,2,3,4,5), y = c(1,2,3,4,5)) %>%
  mutate(
    grid_id = paste(x,y) # just some values
  ) %>%
  as.data.table(.)

B <- data.frame(
    ID = c(1,2,3),     
    xb = c(2,3,4), 
    yb = c(2,3,4)
  ) %>% 
  mutate(
      x_upper = xb + limit
    , x_lower = xb - limit
    , y_upper = yb + limit
    , y_lower = yb - limit
) %>%
  as.data.table(.)

result <- A[B, 
       on = .(x >= x_lower, x <= x_upper, y >= y_lower, y <= y_upper),
       .(x, y, xb, yb, ID, grid_id)]
```

Current output below:

```
> result
    x y xb yb  ID grid_id
 1: 3 3  2  2 2_2     1 1
 2: 3 3  2  2 2_2     2 1
 3: 3 3  2  2 2_2     3 1
 4: 3 3  2  2 2_2     1 2
 5: 3 3  2  2 2_2     2 2
 6: 3 3  2  2 2_2     3 2
 7: 3 3  2  2 2_2     1 3
 8: 3 3  2  2 2_2     2 3
 9: 3 3  2  2 2_2     3 3
10: 4 4  3  3 3_3     2 2
11: 4 4  3  3 3_3     3 2
12: 4 4  3  3 3_3     4 2
13: 4 4  3  3 3_3     2 3
14: 4 4  3  3 3_3     3 3
15: 4 4  3  3 3_3     4 3
16: 4 4  3  3 3_3     2 4
17: 4 4  3  3 3_3     3 4
18: 4 4  3  3 3_3     4 4
19: 5 5  4  4 4_4     3 3
20: 5 5  4  4 4_4     4 3
21: 5 5  4  4 4_4     5 3
22: 5 5  4  4 4_4     3 4
23: 5 5  4  4 4_4     4 4
24: 5 5  4  4 4_4     5 4
25: 5 5  4  4 4_4     3 5
26: 5 5  4  4 4_4     4 5
27: 5 5  4  4 4_4     5 5
    x y xb yb  ID grid_id
```

Comment: This is (unfortunately) a common confusion in non-equi joins in `data.table`. The columns in the result get their names from `x` (here the "A" table) and their values from `i` (here the "B" table). The relevant part of `?data.table`: "Columns of `x` can now be referred to using the prefix `x.` and is particularly useful during joining to refer to `x`'s join columns as they are otherwise masked by `i`'s." Thus: `A[B, on = .(x >= x_lower, x <= x_upper, y >= y_lower, y <= y_upper), .(x.x, x.y, xb, yb, ID, grid_id)]`.

Comment: This peculiarity is nicely explained in this PR: [SQL-like column return for non-equi and rolling joins](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/2706). See also a [similar SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52793148/1851712) (possible duplicate)

Comment: Relevant quote from the PR: "When performing any join, only one copy of each key column is returned in the result. Currently, the column from `i` is returned, and labelled with the column name from `x`, making equi joins consistent with the behaviour of base `merge()`. This causes confusion for many people"

Comment: This is indeed confusing (same as the **order** of LHS and RHS in the condition), thank you for pointing out this one can be corrected with proper syntax. And, well, thumbs up to `data.table` for trying anyway - non-equivalent joins are not available in `dplyr` at all ;).